# Dart camera has weird image dimensions / aspect ratios during processing even though it appears as normal image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, camera

note: I am new to Flutter and facing a dead end after some troubleshooting on an image captured with camera issue, any insights / help that can point me to any direction is very much appreciated.

I am facing a weird issue with photos taken with my flutter app . The images look fine and metadata seems ok, however processing with machine learning model that identify with coordinates is off. (image 1). The processing is successful to a certain extent (able to identify items successfully), but bounding box coordinates are way off (image 2 & 3)

About the app:
The app takes image > post to backend for processing with Machine learning model trained and identify items (backend is on AWS if that matters). Image stored in s3 bucket, processing done with lambda and i have trained machine learning models based off my fridge images shown below. The recognition will identify respective items with bounding box. Example (Image 1)

[image: Image 1]

Issue:
However, no matter what devices I use (ios/ android), whenever I use my Flutter app to take the images and upload, the image appears ok in s3, but the processing of the bounding box is very off.

Example: (Image 2 & 3) Please ignore the resolution that is relatively low, i have tried with multiple high resolution and similar quality image as image 1, but results still show the same.
[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

I did not do anything in my code with the image before posting to s3. From the bounding box, it seems that the image ratio / dimensions is off somehow, but yet image shows ok in s3. My code for the image capture and posting is shared at the bottom.

What I have done to troubleshoot and rule out potential issues to find the root cause:

- I tried 2 different libraries, 1 is through the camera package https://pub.dev/packages/camera (^0.10.5+3) , another with image picker library https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker (^1.0.4), both image taken returns similar result. But when i use image picker gallery source to load from the image taken with the react app or webcam, the result shows normal (i.e. similar to image 1).
- I tried with other (React app / webcam) for similar backend processing, (all condition remains the same, lighting etc, items position, different devices etc). All returns results that are similar. Bounding box is not off.
- Upload via direct / API gateway, both returns the same result. I also tried uploading with image picker with the image taken with other app (React), the image will be processed and bounding box identified ok like image 1.
- also tried with images across different resolutions, and ruled out issue caused by resolution, because ultra high resolution still shows the bounding box coordinates is way off. (although able to identify successfully)

My code for image capture and uploading:

Using normal camera library (camera has been initialized ok)

### Image capture and then to `DisplayPictureScreen` that display the picture and post to s3 upon pressing Upload button.

```
FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await cameraController.takePicture();

            if (!mounted) return;

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            debugPrint(e.toString());
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
```

### Display Picture and upload screen

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Upload and detect for ingredients')),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.file(File(imagePath)),
            ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Upload'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // HTTP POST request to perform file upload
                  File imageFile = File(imagePath);
                  const region = 'us-west-2';
                  const signer = AWSSigV4Signer();
                  final scope = AWSCredentialScope(
                      region: region, service: AWSService.s3);
                  const bucketName = 'upload-bucket-name';
                  const host = '$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com';
                  final serviceConfiguration = S3ServiceConfiguration();

// Create a file and write some contents to it. Then, open it
// for reading.
                  final Directory directory =
                      await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                  final filename = File('${directory.path}/testImage.jpg');
                  print(filename.path);
                  final uint8List = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
                  final file = filename..writeAsBytesSync(uint8List);
                  final contents = file.openRead();
                  const key = '/testImage.jpg';

// Create a PUT request to the path of the file.
                  print('creating upload requests...');
                  final uploadRequest = AWSStreamedHttpRequest.raw(
                    method: AWSHttpMethod.put,
                    host: host,
                    // uri: Uri.parse('http://$host'),
                    path: key,
                    body: contents,
                    headers: {
                      AWSHeaders.host: host,
                      AWSHeaders.contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                    },
                  );

// Sign and send the upload request
                  print('signing and sending upload requests...');
                  final signedUploadRequest = await signer.sign(
                    uploadRequest,
                    credentialScope: scope,
                    serviceConfiguration: serviceConfiguration,
                  );
                  final uploadResponse = await signedUploadRequest.send();
                }
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Apart from using AWS dart SDK https://pub.dev/packages/aws_signature_v4, I also tried another way with uploading via API Gateway and firebase auth login as user (initially thought that might be the issue with API gateway changed any metadata)

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Upload and detect for ingredients')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.file(File(imagePath)),
            ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Upload'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                  final idToken = await user?.getIdTokenResult();

                  // HTTP POST request to perform file upload
                  File imageFile = File(imagePath);

                  // http upload - agw
                  final http.Response response;
                  try {
                    response = await http.post(
                        Uri.parse(
                            "https://my-api-gateway-url.amazonaws.com/Prod/"),
                        // Send authorization headers to the backend.
                        headers: {
                          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
                              idToken!.token.toString(),
                          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'image/jpeg',
                        },
                        // body: blob);
                        body: imageFile.readAsBytesSync());

                    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
                    final int length = result.length;
                    debugPrint(result.toString());

                    if (length == 0) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const NoResultScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      await Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ListIngredientsPage(
                            resultData: result,
                            resultLength: length,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  } on Exception catch (_) {
                    rethrow;
                  } 
                }
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the EXIF information for the problematic files? Possibly they have embedded rotation, resulting in some picture viewers displaying them rotated when they actually aren't. I had this issue when uploading images captured from camera on some devices and my solution was to remove any exif info from the file before processing it serverside.

Comment: thanks! i got this. Seems that the "Image Orientation = Rotated 90 CW" 

Do you encountered this as well? i am confused as of why it will set the metadata rotated by default. 

more details:
I/flutter (10987): Image ImageWidth = 4080
I/flutter (10987): Image ImageLength = 3060
I/flutter (10987): Image Make = samsung
I/flutter (10987): Image Model = SM-A135F
I/flutter (10987): Image Orientation = Rotated 90 CW
I/flutter (10987): Image XResolution = 72
I/flutter (10987): Image YResolution = 72
I/flutter (10987): Image ResolutionUnit = Pixels/Inch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what @Wh1t3rabbit guided, it turns up that it's due to the metadata of the image file. Not sure why by default, the flutter app created an image that has metadata of the `Image Orientation = Rotated 90 CW`. Hence it interferes the ML processing backend because the processing retrieve the image and calculate the bounding box based on coordinates.

I did this as a workaround:

- Use exif package https://pub.dev/packages/exif to investigate the metadata

#### to retrieve the EXIF of the image file:

```
final fileBytes = cleanFilename.readAsBytesSync();
final data = await readExifFromBytes(fileBytes);
debugPrint('image metadata: ');
for (final e in data.entries) {
    debugPrint('${e.key} = ${e.value}');
}
```

- After which, I remove the EXIF data with flutter compress package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress and save as new file, before uploading to s3 for further processing

#### Removing EXIF of the image file

(credits to https://medium.com/swlh/removing-metadata-exif-data-from-images-in-flutter-fbefd615c554)

```
final Directory directory =
await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final filename = File('${directory.path}/testImage.jpg');
final targetPath = '${directory.path}/cleanImage.jpg';
await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      filename.path, targetPath);

debugPrint(targetPath);
final cleanFilename = File(targetPath);
```

Hope this helps anyone with some clue for those who faced similar unexplainable situation again.